# How to know the position of StackView in Android 3.0..OnItemClick is returning 0 everytime

Tags: android

I m tring to get the position of My views when i click on them in StackView but its always returning zero unlike other ViewGroups like Gallery,ListView and GridView.OnSelectedListener also not working ..can anyone help plz???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i got the answer...there is a method called getDisplayedChild() which returns the index of the current view like in other ViewGroups

Comment: How to Perform something like OnclickListener using StackView.I need to do something onSwipe on StackView ?i don't to make use of OnClick,OnItemSelected,OnTouch kind of ...!!Thanks in Advance